# bash docker tag multiple images only re-tag if it is found

Tags: bash, docker, awk

This is the output of `docker images`:

```
REPOSITORY                        TAG           IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
my.website.com/image-back         prod          0970fe98b4fb   22 minutes ago   782MB
my.website.com/image-api          prod          dbce64b7b0e8   22 minutes ago   719MB
my.website.com/postgres           15.1-alpine   f8428074961e   8 months ago     243MB
nginx                             alpine        433dbc17191a   2 weeks ago      42.6MB
hello-world                       latest        9c7a54a9a43c   4 months ago     13.3kB
```

What I expect to be done:

- for each image in the output, run this: `docker tag $my.website.com/image:TAG image:TAG`

This only happens if the first column starts with `my.website.com/`, and I want to tag my images without this domain name. The my.website.com is my website and is a private repo, and I downloaded in another server, now I want to remove this name in order to modify Dockerfiles in the project.

Expected output:

```
REPOSITORY                        TAG           IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
image-back                        prod          0970fe98b4fb   28 minutes ago   782MB
my.website.com/image-back         prod          0970fe98b4fb   28 minutes ago   782MB
image-api                         prod          dbce64b7b0e8   28 minutes ago   719MB
my.website.com/image-api          prod          dbce64b7b0e8   28 minutes ago   719MB
postgres                          15.1-alpine   f8428074961e   8 months ago     243MB
my.website.com/postgres           15.1-alpine   f8428074961e   8 months ago     243MB
nginx                             alpine        433dbc17191a   2 weeks ago      42.6MB
hello-world                       latest        9c7a54a9a43c   4 months ago     13.3kB
```

This is my (of course failed) attempt:

```
docker tag $(docker images -a | awk 'FNR>=2 {print $1":"$2}') $(docker images -a | awk 'FNR>=2 {print $1":"$2}' | sed -E 's/(my.website.com\/)//g')
```

Comment: Can you use a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) in a higher-level language, rather than try to do this only through shell string manipulation?

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the link, but I think by using the current answer `docker image ls ...`, I'm using the Docker API too. Any benefits for directly using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
docker image ls |
    awk -F' +|/' '/my\.website\.com/ && NR>1{print $4, $2":"$3}' |
    xargs -r -n2 echo docker tag
```

Remove `echo` statement when the output looks good enough.